# How can I stop multiple case update notifications being sent?

Tags: formula, process-builder, servicecloud, case-object, criteria

I've created a PB which notifies the case owner whenever a case they own is updated.

The issue is that I have a number of child objects (and processes) which update the case record when an action is performed so, for example, if an email is received whilst a case is in an 'Awaiting Customer Update' status then the following will happen:

- A WF will change the status to 'Working'.
- A cases status change record will be created and a roll-up summary field, on the case record, will be updated.
- A 'Customer Has Replied' tickbox will be checked.

This results in 3 notifications being sent to the case owner.

To combat unnecessary notifications I have applied the following criteria:

```
AND( 
(NOW() - [Case].LastModifiedDate) > 0.00069444444,

$User.Id <> '005D0000008gAFhIAM',

$User.Id <> [Case].OwnerId,

BEGINS([Case].OwnerId, "005"),

NOT(ISPICKVAL($Profile.UserType, "Guest")), 

NOT(ISPICKVAL([Case].Status, "Archived")),

NOT(ISPICKVAL([Case].Status, "Awaiting Customer Update")), 

NOT(ISPICKVAL([Case].Status, "Solved"))

)
```

However, neither **$User.Id <> [Case].User.Id** (don't send a notification if the update is performed by the case owner) and **(NOW() - [Case].LastModifiedDate) > 0.00069444444** (don't send an update if the the case has already been modified in the last 1 minute) are working.

Any idea how I can make this work, please?

Comment: Update, I'd not taken into account that the following can be 15 or 18 chars in length so CASESAFEID() is required.

CASESAFEID($User.Id) <> CASESAFEID([Case].OwnerId),

Comment: What else do you do in you PB Flow, can you disable the "allow to run more than once per transaction" option without losing other functionality?